# How to properly unescape strace output

Tags: linux, parsing, strace

How do I unescape strings outputted by `strace`? I see some advices to use `printf '%b'` for that, but that doesn't work correctly for me in some cases. Consider `echo -ne '\037\061'`:

```
$ strace -e write echo -ne '\037\061'
write(1, "\0371", 21)                    = 2
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Now, if I feed this into `printf`:

```
$ printf "%b" "\0371" | xxd -p
f9
```

While in reality it was:

```
$ echo -ne '\037\061' | xxd -p
1f31
```

Obviously, `printf %b` interprets `\0371` as `\371` (as it should, according to the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf)). This means `printf` is not really suitable for decoding `strace` output. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr – see "conclusion" at the very end.

---

What happens here is quite interesting.

First of all `echo -e` acts like this (from [`man 1 echo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo)):

> `\0NNN`
>   byte with octal value `NNN` (1 to 3 digits)

This means `0` in `\037` is not an octal digit, it's just a part of `\0` prefix that indicates consecutive octal input. Your `\037` may be `\0037` and now only the second `0` is an octal digit.

Still within `echo -e` `\061` is equivalent to `\0061`. This is equivalent to `1`, a literal character meaning "one".

Now it seems that the part of `strace` output you want to decode should be decoded this way:

```
write(1, "\0371", 21)
          ^     prefix that indicates consecutive octal output
           ^^^  three digits of octal output
              ^ literal character meaning "one"
```

So the prefix here is not `\0` but `\`.

You use `printf "%b" "\0371"`. The general form is `printf FORMAT [ARGUMENT]…` and this is what [`man 1 printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) says about `FORMAT` being `%b`:

> `%b`
>   `ARGUMENT` as a string with `\` escapes interpreted, except that octal escapes are of the form `\0` or `\0NNN`

As you can see the prefix is `\0`, like in `echo -e`. The interpretation now goes like this:

```
printf "%b" "\0371"
             ^^    prefix that indicates consecutive octal input
               ^^^ three octal digits
```

This explains your wrong result. However the same manual states that inside `FORMAT` octal digits are interpreted in a slightly different way:

> `\NNN`
>   byte with octal value `NNN` (1 to 3 digits)

The prefix is `\` exactly as in the output of `strace`. Additionally `strace` seems to take care whenever the next character can be interpreted as an octal digit. Compare:

```
$ strace -e write echo -ne '\037'
write(1, "\37", 1)                      = 1
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

to

```
$ strace -e write echo -ne '\037\101'
write(1, "\37A", 21)                    = 2
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

to

```
$ strace -e write echo -ne '\037\061'
write(1, "\0371", 21)                    = 2
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Note the leading `0` in the last case. It's there to avoid `\371` which would be interpreted as a single byte.

It looks like you could use `printf` to decode `strace` output, but you should pass it as `FORMAT`, not `ARGUMENT`:

```
$ printf "\0371" | xxd -p
1f31
```

*But then* other sequences interpreted inside `FORMAT` (e.g. `%b`) would get you in trouble, so it's better to stick to `ARGUMENT`. I played with `sed` to turn `\` into `\0` in proper cases, it got cumbersome fast; then I realized `%b` as `FORMAT` will also interpret other sequences in `ARGUMENT`! In my opinion it's a dead end.

---

Conclusion: it's way better to change the behavior of `strace`. Try hex output:

```
$ strace -xx -e write echo -ne '\037\061'
write(1, "\x1f\x31", 21)                    = 2
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Then

```
$ printf "%b" "\x1f\x31" | xxd -p
1f31
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I don't like the idea of using `-x` though: it makes the output a lot harder to read (now I need to decode everything!). `strace -xe write echo -ne '\037z'` results in `"\x1f\x7a"` instead of much more useful `"\x1fz"`, which makes it a lot harder to look for the syscal I'm after in the `strace` output